# MySQL Where date is greater than one month?

Tags: mysql

I have a datetime column called 'last_login'.

I want to query my database to select all records that haven't logged in within the last month. How do I do this?

This is what I have currently:

```
$query = $this->query("SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, u.registered, g.name as group_name FROM `:@users` AS u LEFT JOIN `:@groups` AS g on u.group_id = g.id WHERE u.last_login = ...... LIMIT {$limit_start}, {$limit_end}");
```

:@ = database prefix

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try using [`date_sub`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

```
where u.last_login < date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
```

(Similar to the first answer but in my mind it is more "natural" to use positive integers)

Comment: How so? @JasonS wants to find all users who have not logged in to the system in the last month. That means their last login date will be prior to one month ago. Therefore, we want to restrict records to those having a last_login before (i.e. less than) the date one month ago from now(). Using > would give you only the users who's last login was during the last month.

Comment: This statement indeed correctly retrieves users that have last_login set to over a month ago. So all records returned would be records that have not logged_in for at least a month. Looking at the date intervval, you see that this selects dates that are prior to a month ago, so the < operator is ok

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`date_add`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) combined with [`now`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

```
...where u.last_login < date_add(now(), interval -1 month)
```

Naturally, as both are MySQL-specific this limits you to MySQL backends. Alternately, you can figure out what the date was a month ago with PHP (I'm not a PHP person, but I'm guessing [`DateTime::sub`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) would help with that) and then include that date in your query in the normal way you would any other date/time field.

Answer (score -1):

matthewh was almost correct, except the `>` should have been a right one.

`where u.last_login > date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)`

Comment: I disagree, using > will give you users who's last login was greater than the date one month ago today - that is, they have logged in during the last month.

Comment: Your expression resulted in showing users who have logged in during the last one month, instead. The questioner wanted to see users who haven't logged in for one month.