# MySQL Where DateTime is greater than today

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to get every record from my MySQL database which is greater than today.

Sample:

```
"Go to Lunch","2014-05-08 12-00-00"
"Go to Bed","2014-05-08 23-00-00"
```

Output should only:

```
"Go to Bed","2014-05-08 23-00-00"
```

I use the DateTime for the Date Column

Already searched:

- [MySQL Where date is greater than one month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237594/mysql-where-date-is-greater-than-one-month)
- [Datetime equal or greater than today in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182275/datetime-equal-or-greater-than-today-in-mysql)

But this does not work for me.

QUERY(FOR PHP):

```
SELECT `name`,`date` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`datum` >= DATE(NOW())
```

OR (FOR PhpMyAdmin)

```
SELECT `name`,`date` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`datum` >= 2014-05-18 15-00-00;
```

How can I write the working query?

Comment: Using dashes in the hours/minutes/seconds is not a great idea. Use `23:00:00` instead.

Comment: Today is May 18th where I am (and in most of the world).  Why would a query to get dates in the future return a row with "2014-05-08" as the date?

Comment: There's something odd about saying you want everything greater than today, but then include `2014-05-08 23-00-00`, which would seem to indicate the same day (not greater than today).

Comment: For the query, you were just missing some single quotes around the date value.    

`SELECT \`name\`,\`date\` FROM \`tasks\` WHERE \`tasks\`.\`datum\` >= '2014-05-18 15-00-00'`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Remove the `date()` part

```
SELECT name, datum 
FROM tasks 
WHERE datum >= NOW()
```

and if you use a specific date, don't forget the quotes around it and use the proper format with `:`

```
SELECT name, datum 
FROM tasks 
WHERE datum >= '2014-05-18 15:00:00'
```

Comment: I don't know that today is equivalent to now.

Comment: Thank You, This works for me. I also write the WHERE after the ORDER By. But now it works :D

Answer (score 9):

I guess you looking for `CURDATE()` or `NOW()` .

```
  SELECT name, datum 
  FROM tasks 
  WHERE datum >= CURDATE()
```

LooK the rsult of NOW and CURDATE

```
   NOW()                    CURDATE()        
   2008-11-11 12:45:34      2008-11-11
```

Comment: I suspect the OP may also have dashes in their time. That could be contributing to "nothing is working".

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
WHERE joiningdate >= NOW();
```

Comment: Your answer is as same as accepted answer!! - Please remove your post and keep SO clean ;).