# How would I run a query across all tables in a database (MySQL) to find a date string value that is greater than todays date?

Tags: mysql

what I have is a single database with multiple tables on a server that I want to run a query against to find the values of any fields, in any table, that have a date greater than today's (current day) date.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Where DateTime is greater than today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722352/mysql-where-datetime-is-greater-than-today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single table the query is >>

```
SELECT * FROM db_name.`table_name` WHERE date_column_name >= CURRENT_DATE;
```

Now for running it on multipe tables you will need to use JOINS. According to the structure of result and usage you can use any of the joins. Read about them [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). You can just add the Join clause in the query above.

Comment: @Karthik your query seems same normal select query. I think UmairK looking something different.

Comment: thanks but @kuttyraj is correct, I am looking for a query that I can run across all tables in the database at once

Comment: Since you don't know which fields are date fields and what their purpose is, won't this be a little futile? You should be specifying which tables and fields are to be queried.

Comment: I suppose you're right in that sense. I've requested more information myself with regards to specific tables and columns, but then it would easy enough to execute the query. No need to answer this one any further guys. Thanks